# Blank page with Polymer

Tags: html, polymer, wamp

I am following [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wId1gMzriRE) and I have seen every previous video in the tutorial series.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
        <link rel="import" href="elements/hello-world.html">
    </head>
    <body>
        <hello-world></hello-world>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the second page:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<polymer-element name='hello-world' noscript>
    <template>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

But my page is still blank, what am I doing wrong?

I use Wamp.

Comment: Which version of Polymer do you use. And is there anything in the Console

Comment: thaaaaaaaaaaanks for the answer!!!! so i use bower and if i go to http://localhost/polymer/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html the page still blank... and where i could fine the version?

Comment: the version is in your bower.json ``"polymer": "Polymer/polymer#~0.5.0"``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's always happen to me if i'm not correctly import an element or library. So make sure all path locations are correct.

Make sure you use 0.5 version because in 0.8 custom element declaration is using `<dom-module id="element-name"></dom-module>`

Answer (score 0):

First check your polymer version. it is found on `bower.json` under `dependencies`
check `"polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^1.7.0"` as you can see mine is 1.7.0. if you are using **polymer 1.0 and above**. the custom element declaration has been changed.
Here is a detailed note on what you have to do.

1. Change `<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>` to `<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>`
2. Custom element declaration has also been changed from
   `<polymer-element name="hello-world">
       <template>
           <div>Hello World</div>
       </template>
       <script>
           Polymer();
       </script>
   </polymer-element>`
   to

`<dom-module id="hello-world">
        <template>
            <div>Hello World</div>
        </template>
        <script>
            Polymer({
                     is: "hello-world"
                   });
        </script>
  </dom-module>`

Check The Migration Guide Page https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration